# Gravatar call not respecting default tag?

Tags: javascript, gravatar

As per the Gravatar instructions, I have the following function that gets a users Gravatar:

```
import crypto from 'crypto';

function gravatar(email, size) {
      size = size || 100
      let d = encodeURIComponent(`https://example.com/img/default-avatar.jpg`)
      return `https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/${crypto.createHash('md5').update(email).digest("hex")}?s=${size}?d=${d}`
    }
```

This function works, but when an email address that Gravatar doesn't recognise is passed, it does not respect the default parameter.  Instead I end up with the default blue G icon.

I have also replaced `d` with `mp`, and I still get the default blue G.

Is this my function, or could it be something wrong with the Gravatar service?
https://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/

Comment: You have a typo here: `...est("hex")}?s=${size}?d=${d}` it should be `...est("hex")}?s=${size}&d=${d}`. Please note `&` before `d` instead of `?`. Otherwise `d` is ignored.

Comment: Wow, can't believe I missed that. Thanks